# Does all total sets have a "stable" property?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

In Kreyszig's *Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications*, a total set in a normed space $X$ is defined as a subset $M \subset X$ whose span is dense in $X$. That is,
$\overline{\text{span } M} = X$.

Let $X$ be a separable normed space, and $M = \{f_1, f_2, \dotsc\}$ be a countable total set in $X$.
Prove or disprove the following: For each $x \in X$, there exist coefficients $c_1, c_2, \dotsc$, such that $\|x - \sum_{k=1}^n c_k f_k\| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Note that $c_k$ does not change for each $n$, which is what I try to imply by "stable".

Note: The question may be badly posed in the sense that there may still be assumptions I need to make, otherwise there will be a trivial answer. It's a personal question rather than a homework question.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but isn't $C[0,1]$ with the sup norm, $f_n(x)=x^n$ a simple example?

Comment: I think you got it! Every $f \in C[0,1]$ that can be written as a series of $f_n$ are analytic and hence differentiable. Then every continuous but non-differentiable functions in $C[0,1]$ will not have the series representation despite $M$ being total in $C[0,1]$ by Weierstrass approximation theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requiring $c_k$ to remain fixed during the approximation process is a strong restriction, as you can see by looking at $f_n(x)=x^n$ on $C[0,1]$ with the sup norm. (Here $n$ starts from $0$ of course.) Weierstrass' theorem says this is total, but given a sequence $c_k$, if $\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k x^k$ converges uniformly then the limit is analytic.

Answer (score 2):

If the countable set $M$ has the property you describe it is said to be a *[Schauder basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis)* for $X$; this term appears in Kreyszig's book, so you can see it there as well.

Lots of separable Banach spaces do have a Schauder basis, including $\ell^p$ or $L^p[0,1]$ for $1 \le p < \infty$.

Exhibiting a separable Banach space which does not have a Schauder basis is possible, but difficult. Enflo constructed an example in this paper: Enflo, P., *[A counterexample to the approximation property in Banach spaces](http://www.cnd.mcgill.ca/~ivan/PerEnfloAcounterexampleToTheApproximationProblemInBanachSpaces.pdf)*, Acta Math. 130, 309–317 (1973). Note that existence of a Schauder basis implies that a Banach space has the approximation property.

Comment: This is a good answer to a slightly different question: the OP asks whether every total set is a Schauder basis, you ask whether every Banach space has *some* Schauder basis.

Comment: @Ian: Okay, but my answer implies a negative answer to the OP's question since any Schauder basis is total. That being said, your explicit example of a countable total set which is not a Schauder basis is nice.

Comment: I don't think it does, the OP's question is "is a given total set a Schauder basis?"

Comment: I agree he is asking: "is every countable total set a Schauder basis?" So, if there is a separable Banach space $X$ with countable dense set $M$ that does not have a Schauder basis (per Enflo), then $M$ is total (since it is already dense) but it is not a Schauder basis (since $X$ doesn't have one); thereby providing a counterexample to the OP's question.